# Looping through multidimensional array and checking conditions

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this.

```
[
  0 => array:3 [
    "volume" => 1272.0
    "overflow" => 0
    "deficit" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "volume" => 2352.0
    "overflow" => 0
    "deficit" => 0
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "volume" => 3144.0
    "overflow" => 0
    "deficit" => 0
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    "volume" => 6048.0
    "overflow" => 0
    "deficit" => 0
  ]
  4 => array:3 [
    "volume" => 8952.0
    "overflow" => 0
    "deficit" => 0
  ]
]
```

I have $count variable which increments when both overflow and deficit are zero in the nested array. To do this, I try the following loop.

```
$keys = array_keys($waterLevels);
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($waterLevels); $i++){
    foreach ($waterLevels[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value)
    {
        if (($key === 'overflow' and $value == 0) and ($key === 'deficit' and $value == 0)){
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this loop, I should get $count value to be 5. I know something is wrong with the 'if' condition. If I try with 'overflow' alone, it works. It does not if I add the next 'and' condition. What logic am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only this much needed:-

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($waterLevels  as $value){
    if ($value['overflow'] == 0 && $value['deficit'] == 0){
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

Output:- https://eval.in/780558